# WebSocket connections cannot be established on edge or chrome but only on safari. what is wrong with my browser?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ws

java code with spring boot starter websocket
`@Configuration @EnableWebSocket public class WsConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer { @Autowired UserWsHandler userWsHandler; @Autowired UserHandlerShakeHandler userHandlerShakeHandler; @Override public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) { registry.addHandler(userWsHandler,"/loginWs") .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*"); }`
js
`.   const ws = new WebSocket("ws://10.12.36.178:8080/loginWs")`

i got a EOFException when use chrome or edge.

Is something wrong with my code or my browser settings？

appreciates～

Answer (score 0):

i am so stupid!

when use header 'Sec-Websocket-Protocol', the server must send back the same header.....